# Shorten number labels in Charts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm making a simple line chart for a client using Chart.js, but the values shown are all above millions, making the labels take up a lot of space in the chart, as below:

[image: Chart]

I would like to shorten the labels to show an M instead of six 0s, for instance.

I've looked into the documentation and and have not found anything of such.

Comment: Simple solution would be to adjust your data, by dividing everything by 1 million before rendering it to the chart - then just having "(in millions)" somewhere on your chart.

Comment: That is not possible. The data is part of a much larger table and in it the values must be seen as proper numbers and not shortened. This graph is just a visual part of a much larger application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could override the `ticks.callback` method as documented here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

For example, to abbreviate the y-axis zeros to simply 'M':

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Abbreviate the millions
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return value / 1e6 + 'M';
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robhirstio/hsvxbjkg/17/

Comment: works great, but how do we commarize ONLY if the delta is high enough? E.g. if the chart is from 1,000,100 to 1,000,50 at some interval, the difference is too little and it would show 1M for every label (so not very useful to the user)

Answer (score 3):

Adding commarize feature for `k, M, B and T`

```
function commarize(min) {
  min = min || 1e3;
  // Alter numbers larger than 1k
  if (this >= min) {
    var units = ["k", "M", "B", "T"];

    var order = Math.floor(Math.log(this) / Math.log(1000));

    var unitname = units[(order - 1)];
    var num = Math.floor(this / 1000 ** order);

    // output number remainder + unitname
    return num + unitname
  }

  // return formatted original number
  return this.toLocaleString()
}
```

In chart JS you could use config property  `ticks` into `yAxes`

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return String(value).commarize(); 
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Chart JS Reference https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html
Commarize reference https://gist.github.com/MartinMuzatko/1060fe584d17c7b9ca6e

Answer (score 2):

Support `'K', 'M', 'B'`:

This is my solution, to be generic when you use the same `options` object for multiple charts, that possibly contain lower numbers or negative numbers.

```
formatNumbers(value) {
  if (value >= 1000000000 || value <= -1000000000 ) {
    return value / 1e9 + 'B';
  } else if (value >= 1000000 || value <= -1000000) {
    return value / 1e6 + 'M';
  } else  if (value >= 1000 || value <= -1000) {
    return value / 1e3 + 'K';
  }
  return value;
}
```

My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/epsilontal/v0qnsbwk/45/

Example:

[image]